# WinUI 3 - How can I add text on grid border?

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I want to "name" some grids in my program like this, so it is easier to navigate through it:
[So I want to sign all grids on their Border]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGr8o.jpg)

I was onle able to achieve this:
[What I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQZLH.png)

I did it by putting both Grid and TextBlock in the same position in another, bigger Grid

```
 <TextBlock
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Text="Test"
            Margin="5, 0, 0, 0"/>
 <Grid
            Name="eingabeAndTabs"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Padding="5"
            Margin="0,10,0,0"
            BorderBrush="Gray"
            BorderThickness="2">
```

Is there any way to make it look better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to surround your `Grid` by a `GroupBox`?

```
<GroupBox Name="Test">
      
    <Grid Name="eingabeAndTabs" ... />
        
</GroupBox>
```

Comment: Your idea worked, but in order to add GroupBox in WinUI one need to download this control library: https://github.com/DHancock/WinUI3Controls
After that it worked just as expected. [The result](https://imgur.com/a/vdyuemP)